# What is the sport of Horse Boarding?

Tags: horses

Recently a [user](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/3313/aravona) mentioned something called Horse Boarding. At first I thought she was talking about boarding horses, like in a stable, but she was actually referring to an activity that's popular, especially in the UK.

What exactly is the sport of horse-boarding? How is it done? Is it only in the UK, or in other parts of the world?

Comment: Did you ask this on March 31 in your time zone?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yup, I did. Is there any special reason why you're asking?

Comment: checking it wasn't an April Fool's Day prank.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm That's funny, I didn't even think about that! This came out of a discussion in chat where Aravona mentioned it, and it intrigued me. Having learned from her, it now intrigues me more! I'm in the United States, so my time is earlier than a number of the people here. I just checked what time it is where you are, I had no idea it was so much different. I definitely would have posted this on April 1 in your area!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Horse boarding](http://www.horseboardinguk.org/) is a sport similar to kite boarding / kite surfing where one uses wind power via a kite to pull oneself along on a long-board type skateboard or surfboard.

With Horse Boarding you are pulled along by a horse and rider. This gives added complexity - one because you're doubling (tripling if you include the horse) the number of participants.

It is considered an extreme sport in a similar way to 3 day eventing (people die doing cross country where jumps go wrong). The idea being to run a course at the fastest time with least faults - same as all horse events, lowest score wins.

> DESCRIPTION OF ARENA BOARDING
>
> 8.1 Teams compete against the clock around a course defined by a series of gates and obstacles.
>
> 8.2 The course comprises a series of gates that should be 4 m wide, other obstacles, and designated Start and Finish.
>
> 8.3 Teams wait in a collecting or pits area, and enter the main part of the arena when called by the pits officials.
>
> 8.4 The competition comprises runs over Course A and Course B. Course B is the reverse of
> Course A.

Full rules below as there are a lot!

**It is international!**

> Horseboarding International has been set up by Horseboarding UK to promote and develop the sport of horseboarding worldwide.
>
> Managed by the founder of the sport in the UK, Daniel Fowler-Prime and together with his highly experienced Horseboarding UK team, it aims to promote and encourage the development of the sport through the establishment of national organisations within individual countries, under a standard system of rules, procedures and values.

There are also a number of complicated rules that you have to pass in order to be able to compete, these include rules for the horse rider, for the board rider, and for the horses welfare:

http://www.horseboardinguk.org/images/downloads/Horseboarding-UK-General-Rules-2017.pdf

I never got to do this as it's more recent than my riding career but I have watched it at country shows and it is a lot of fun (also lead to me kindly asking my dad 'Daddy I need another pony!' for a laugh).

[Horse boarding youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6qxup2aDWKo)

Comment: Also, if it's done on snow, it is called skijoring (including a horse, dog, or something else is doing the pulling).

Comment: @user3067860 interesting! Not something you'd get in the UK though lol

Comment: That's so fascinating! It's definitely complicated, but I love that the rules are set up to protect everyone, especially the horses!